# Mismatched types error message when instantiating a contract and updating metadata

Tags: archway-network, cosmwasm

Can anyone explain what what I'm doing wrong here? At the end of the instantiate function I am trying to update the contract's metadata but getting the following error:

```
mismatched types
expected struct `cosmwasm_std::Response<cosmwasm_std::Empty>`
   found struct `cosmwasm_std::Response<archway_bindings::ArchwayMsg>
```

The following is the code snippet of the instantiate function where at the end you can see a new response is generated with a message set after updating the contract metadata:

```rust
#[cfg_attr(not(feature = "library"), entry_point)]
pub fn instantiate(
    deps: DepsMut,
    env: Env,
    _info: MessageInfo,
    msg: InstantiateMsg,
) -> Result<Response, ContractError> {
    let config = Config {
        native_denom: msg.native_denom,
    };
    CONFIG.save(deps.storage, &config)?;
    ADMIN_FEE.save(deps.storage, &msg.admin_fee)?;
    CREDIT_CONTRACT.save(deps.storage, &msg.credit_contract)?;
    set_contract_version(deps.storage, CONTRACT_NAME, CONTRACT_VERSION)?;
    Ok(
        Response::new().add_message(ArchwayMsg::UpdateContractMetadata {
            owner_address: todo!(),
            rewards_address: todo!(),
        }),
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your return type, you wrote

```rust
pub fn instantiate(
  // ...
) -> Result<Response, ContractError> { ... }
```

But then you are actually returned a message of type **ArchwayMsg::UpdateContractMetadata**.

What you want to do is probably something like:

```rust
    #[cfg_attr(not(feature = "library"), entry_point)]
    pub fn instantiate(
        deps: DepsMut,
        env: Env,
        _info: MessageInfo,
        msg: InstantiateMsg,
    ) -> ArchwayResult<ContractError> {
        let config = Config {
            native_denom: msg.native_denom,
        };
        CONFIG.save(deps.storage, &config)?;
        ADMIN_FEE.save(deps.storage, &msg.admin_fee)?;
        CREDIT_CONTRACT.save(deps.storage, &msg.credit_contract)?;
        set_contract_version(deps.storage, CONTRACT_NAME, CONTRACT_VERSION)?;
        
        Ok(Response::new()
            .add_attribute("method", "instantiate")
            .add_attribute("owner", info.sender)
            .add_attribute("rewards_address", "TODO")
            .add_attribute("admin_fee", &msg.admin_fee)
            .add_attribute("credit_contract", &msg.credit_contract)
    }
```